# Migrate user profiles to new Active Directory Accounts

Tags: active-directory, user-management, profile

I have a few users in a very old workgroup that log directly into their local machines (Windows XP Pro).  This week they're finally moving to active directory and will need to log into domain accounts instead.  However, some of these users have been around a long time and are somewhat invested in the profiles they have on the local machines.

How can I move those profiles to the new Active Directory accounts, so that things like desktop backgrounds, browser bookmarks, and other potentially "hidden" settings will follow them?  In one case we even have a Windows Media Player playlist we'd like to move seamlessly, though that can be easily re-created if need be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several potential ways to do this. Probably the simplest is to do some variation of the following:

1. Join the domain
2. Log in as the new
   domain user, and log out
3. Log back in
   as an account with admin rights on
   the box (but not either the old or new user accounts)
4. Go to control panel, system,
       advanced
5. in User Profiles, click
       the Settings button
6. Select the
           local user's profile, click on Copy
           To, and browse to the new domain
           user's c:\documents and
           settings\username folder.
7. Click OK.
8. Click the Change button in Permitted
               to use Select the
               domain\username account you just
               copied

Comment: Step 6, should that be,
"Select the LOCAL user's profile, [...]" ? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Chris, you're right-- step 6 should say "local user's profile". I edited it-- thanks for the catch!

Comment: The only downside I can see so far is that it requires the users log into their new accounts once first, but I think I can handle that. I won't get to try it until tomorrow, though.

Comment: Arg, I miss my edit privileges here! Need. More. Rep. :(  Anyway: this worked well enough but I'd really like to clarify some wording of the last three steps.

Comment: One final follow-up note.  This isn't fool-proof. For example, one user had Google Chrome installed, and for some reason her bookmarks were lost in the copy.  So making a backup of the entire profile before starting, including hidden folders, is still a good idea.

Comment: August 2014, Windows 7, similar situation... and "Copy To..." is disabled. Five year old post... What to do?

Comment: @PhilipKelley I wonder if there's a question on meta about that...

Answer (score 2):

You can try transferring the settings with the Files and Settings Transfer Wizard (Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools).

This should export/import most user settings.

Make sure that the machines where you do the export/import have the same OS version / patch level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DFS replication to sync the user profiles to another location.
Super easy :)